# What commands work on PS4?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I used to play Minecraft on PC, but my PC broke and I wasn't able to fix it, so I moved to the PS4. Now with the new version on the whole game, I want to get back into coding once again like before. I saw last night however it wont run some of the old commands I could run on my PC. What commands are available on PS4?

Answer (score 0):

On the wiki there is [a list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#List_and_summary_of_commands) of all the commands and their availability in all the editions.

Here's a list of all the commands that are available on Java Edition (which your PC was probably using) but not available on Bedrock Edition (the edition on the PS4).

- `advancement`
- `bossbar`
- `data`
- `datapack`
- `debug`
- `defaultgamemode`
- `forceload`
- `loot`
- `recipe`
- `schedule`
- `seed`
- `spectate`
- `trigger`
- `worldborder`

#### Multiplayer/Servers

- `ban`
- `ban-ip`
- `banlist`
- `kick`
- `pardon`
- `publish`
- `save-all`
- `save-off`
- `save-on`
- `setidletimeout`
- `stop`
- `team`
- `teammsg`
- `whitelist`

Note: While some commands are available in both editions, the syntax may be different (for example `execute`). Also, keep in mind that there is no NBT in BE and that there are a lot fewer features than in JE.